# How to Stringify Javascript Array into JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have data that looks as such:

```
"team": "Yankees"
"players": ["jeter", "babe ruth", "lou gehrig", "yogi berra"]
```

I have code that takes these values from a form where they are entered as:

"jeter\nbabe ruth\nlou gehrig\n...." and so forth.

They are split using list.split(\n). Everything when logged in the console is working perfectly, but JSON Post request sends a (400) error. It says the string (as seen above in "players") is invalid.

```
const handleMultipleValues = (playersList) => {
    const splitPlayersList = playersList.split("\n");
    const jsonList = {
        team: team,
        players: splitPlayersList,
    }
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(jsonList)
    };
    fetch('/api/players/', requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? and is there an error on the server side you can access? You are stringifying the object and array correctly, so the error is likely on the server side or in some assumption about the shape of the data

Comment: Yep, if you can `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonList))` correctly, the error must be on the server side. These code seems fine.

Comment: The error only occurs when "jsonList" is an array. if I were to set "jsonList" to a single value, such as:

"team": "Yankees",
"players": "Jeter"

(in code):

{
   team: team,
  players: jsonList[0],
}

It works perfectly. But for the purpose of this application, it would cut down significantly on time if I could copy & paste multiple "values" belonging to the same "key" in a single "form submit".

I was thinking to do some kind of loop so that it would make multiple requests per "value" (player) if that would even make sense?

Comment: The important question for you is: what exact data format does the backend expect? Should players be a string or an array or does it even allow for both?

Answer (score 0):

That's totally normal, because you don't send a string to your server.
If I take your code and simply have a php script on server side with one instruction:

```
var_dump($post);
```

the output is:

```
string(76) "{"team":"Yankees","players":["jeter","babe ruth","lou gehrig","yogi berra"]}"
```

That's because you don't send "players" as a string, you stringify the whole body which then parse players as an array.

Try to change your code with this:

```
const jsonList = {
    team: team,
    players: JSON.stringify(splitPlayersList),
  }
```

Assuming server side expects players to be a string, hence the error message...

Comment: Thanks for your response! Tried it, gave me the following error:

{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"}

I think it may be a server-side issue....I'm using Django REST Framework (React JS for frontend).

Maybe I need to fix something in the "Serializer" class to accept this request.

Comment: Then as @devnull69 said, you first need to know exactly what server side is expecting. Which format is required? Without knowing your backend, we can't really help, I mean the new error is mentioning {"detail": } we never saw that var name before...

Answer (score -1):

What's the second "then"? That may be your issue. Try

fetch('/api/players/', requestOptions)
.then((response) => console.log(response.json()))

Comment: I'll try it. Usually if it's single "player" being passed in the "players", it works fine. But when I try to enter a "list", it doesn't work.

So, for instance, I could even do splitPlayersList[0], and it'll post "jeter" correctly. (200 OK)

Comment: This happened:

Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
players: Array(1)
  0: "Not a valid string."
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

Comment: And if you add a .catch() after the single .then()?